# RxJS catchError and return previous value instead of completing?

Tags: rxjs

I have a stream which may or may not error, I would like to catchError in order to return the previous/last value before the error in order to continue the stream and not complete. Something along the lines of this:

```
inputStream$.pipe(catchError(err => inputStream$.previousValue)).subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Anytime `inputStream$` emits an error notification, it's done and it won't emit further values. What do you mean by continue? Resubscribe to `inputStream$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as your observable `inputStream$` emits an error it is finished.

`catchError` allows to concat an observable which emited an error with another observable (the result of the first parameter of `catchError`)
Some examples are available here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html

What you are looking for is probably `retry` which re-subscribe to the source observable (here `inputSteam$`) when the source emits an error. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retry.html